# Error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel' after installing wheel

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi, python-wheel

Even after installing `sudo pip3 install wheel`, I'm getting this error while installing `rust` and other packages. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide more context. You get the error when doing what?

Comment: Most probably because `sudo pip3 install` installs the package in a different context, perhaps even a different Python version. Hard to tell exactly without more details.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: `sudo pip3 anything` is never right.  Use `/path/to/python -m pip install wheel` to explicitly specify the python interpreter.

Comment: No, not really. We need to be able to see how you cause the problem in order to understand what's going wrong. You might also try https://superuser.com instead (search first), for questions about setting up your environment.